# A lot of boys was/were waiting for his/their turn/turns

Tags: grammatical-number

Which one is correct?

1. A lot of boys was waiting for their turns.
2. A lot of boys were waiting for their turns.
3. A lot of boys was waiting for his turn.

Comment: Do you consider *lot* to be a singular unit that's composed of boys (like *a box of boys*), or are you using *a lot* in the same sense as *many*?

Comment: Hello James, and welcome! I second Jason's question. @JasonBassford, if the lot is a single unit, couldn't it be "A lot of boys was waiting for **its** turn"? Cheers!

Comment: @Conrado The interpretation is tricky either way. I think that the point of the sentence is at least to say that every boy has to wait. But to be explicitly clear, it could likely be cleared up with the following change: *There **[was / were]** a lot of boys **(who were) each** waiting for his turn.* In that sentence, the choice of *was* or *were* is based on the meaning (a unit of boys or many boys).

Comment: Jason, I think you're giving the boys far more than enough rope to hang themselves.

A lot of boys - your "unit of boys" - would have to take "was waiting for its turn."
A lot of boys - as "many boys" - were waiting for their turns would always work.
A lot of boys - either way - was waiting for his turn could never work.

James, test such things by dropping what isn't strictly necessary - here, dropping "A lot of…" to leave "(Some/the) boys…"

To that, what must be added?

After that, what happens if the original is carefully restored?